# Is there a table in Oracle Ebs that keeps the change log of the iban information?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-ebs, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I need to see when an iban changed in oracle ebs system. Is there a specific log table for that?

```
SELECT * FROM iby_ext_bank_accounts
```

I checked this table but ı couldnt find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no auditing enabled by default in Oracle EBS for this table. If **Audit Trail** functionality has been setup for this table, there will be a **Shadow Table** named **iby_ext_bank_accounts_a**. Check that table to see if it contains the IBAN column.

Otherwise, please refer to [Enabling Oracle E-Business Suite Audit Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26401_01/doc.122/e22952/T156458T663771.htm) for steps to enable auditing on this application table. **Audit Trail** will create the **Shadow Table** and audit triggers to capture changes on the columns defined for auditing.

1. Set **Audit Trail: Activate** profile option to **True**
2. Select or create the **Audit Installation**
3. Select or create the **Audit Group** and set to **Enabled Requested**
4. Use the **Audit Tables** window to select the additional column(s) to audit
5. Run the **Audit Trail Update Tables Report** to activate changes

The Oracle support note [E-Business Suite Applications Auditing FAQ For Understanding Data Auditing in Oracle Applications Tables using Audit Trail [ID 69660.1]](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20E-Business%20Suite/69660_1.html) has more additional information on using the **Audit Trail** functionality.

Answer (score 0):

As Jason explained, you should activate and use the Oracle EBS standard audit functionality.
It creates database triggers and the required audit tables, but does not provide usable reporting, and the data is not straightforward to understand.

To query the audit data, you can use the [FND Audit Table Changes by Column](https://www.enginatics.com/reports/fnd-audit-table-changes-by-column/) Blitz Report, as explained in the following blog: https://www.enginatics.com/blog/blitz-report-toolkits/how-to-track-master-data-changes-using-oracle-ebs-audit-function-and-blitz-report/

If you have large audit data, you will run into performance issues when querying, as Oracle standard does not create required indexes. After audit table creation, you should create the missing indexes manually as explained [here](https://www.enginatics.com/blog/blitz-report-toolkits/how-to-track-master-data-changes-using-oracle-ebs-audit-function-and-blitz-report/#Reporting_performance_improvement).